# Improve mapping performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm mapping values that I receive from an ajax call. It works pretty well, but it is still not fast enough in ie7 (I'm getting a slow script warning).

I can't figure out any way to make this faster. I've tried using native javascript functions as well, but the speed improvement was negligible. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
var $audit = $('#audit');

$.each(data, function (i, val) {

    if (val != null && val !== '0') {

        $audit.find('input[type="checkbox"].' + i).attr('checked', val == 1);
        $audit.find('input[type="text"].' + i).val(val);
        $audit.find('select.' + i).val(val);
    }

});
```

Some psuedo-html:

```
<div id="audit">
    <input type="text" class="foo1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="foo2" />
    <select class="foo3">
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in data? Have you done any profiling to see where the browser spend it's time?

Comment: How much is `data.length`? Can you provide an example of your markup (e.g. the `.1` and `.2` element blocks)?

Comment: @alexn `data` is JSON, parsed to a javascript object. And ive used console.time to narrow my problem down to this loop.

Comment: Do you mean `<div id="audit">` instead of `<div id+"audit">`? And how many records r u expecting?

Comment: What is the structure of the `data` object? Why don't you use a detailed profiler like http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/dynatrace-ajax-download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if it will help that much but you could cache your inputs + select and just filter that instead of finding the "same" element over and over again and just filter the specific element in a much smaller collection:

```
var $audit = $('#audit'),
    $inputs = $audit.find('input, select');

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    if (val != null && val !== '0') {
        var current = $inputs.filter('.' + i);
        if(current.is(":checkbox") {
            current.attr('checked', val === 1);
        } else {
            current.val(val);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but its actually slower. Probably due to the `is()` check on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `knockout.js` for your purposes. It **may be** faster.

This is an example of data binding:  http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Per iteration, it's not too surprising that its slow when the scope chain keeps entering and leaving the DOM. However that the loop is taking a long time begs the question: how many of these divs are on the page? If it's more than around 50, then you've got a UI design issue.

To get this to go significantly faster really equires a radical redisgn of the code. If it were me, I'd build up an HTML framgent containing the repeating divs as a javascript string then splice it into the page using a single createElement/setting the innerHTML

Comment: So youre saying that `createElement` for each input would be faster than just mapping the values?

Comment: No - that would be about as slow - create a string contianing multiple divs, then use createElement to contain a single div and set it's innerHTML to the string containing multiple entries.